# Regular expression in javascript to get contents of <span> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string with this form

```
<p>Central: <span class="fieldText">Central_Local</span>
<br>Area Resolutoria:  <span class="fieldText">Area_Resolutoria</span>
<br>VPI:  <span class="fieldText">VIP</span>
```

I'm trying to get the `span` elements, and find the values within

```
var message = currentMarker.get("mensaje");
var pat = new RegExp("^(.*?<span .*?>(.*?)</span>.*?)+$");
message.match(pat);
```

I need to get these values:

```
Central_Local
Area_Resolutoria
VIP
IP_ERX
```

How can this be done, or how can my regex be improved?

Comment: Does it have to be done with a regex, or can you use another approach like jQuery?

Comment: Another lost soul trying to parse HTML with Regex. Good luck. And if you want to read about what other people think about it here's a nice post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 Still searching for a regex?

Comment: @p.campbell i can be done with jquery, without troubles =D

Comment: Despite the common mentality and SO meme, parsing HTML with a regex is totally fine if you ***know*** what to expect, i.e. *you* wrote the HTML and it's well formed.

Comment: @Wesley Murch, no, even if you wrote it, it's not fine. I mean, look at the one-liner answers below. Now look at the question. Which one you prefer? The one that will break as soon as some other poor soul inherits this code and tries to modify something or the one which simply works?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: "Fine" meaning "it can work, and be useful in limited situations". I think "totally fine" is not the appropriate description, my mistake. I didn't mean to take away from the validity of your comment.

Comment: @Wesley Murch, StackOverflow is not only for *it will work answers*. It's about teaching best practices. It's a well referenced site and we absolutely don't want some other poor soul having the same problem in the future googling about a solution, falling upon this question and seeing a regex, do we? We want to reference only what's considered to be good practices (by a large community of developers) in a given situation.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I do wish the de facto post about it was less humorous, and more clear as to why it is considered a bad idea. The first sentence or two begins to explain, then of course the other 95% is gibberish. If I landed there from a google search, I would still be seeking clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery

```
var message = currentMarker.get("mensaje");
var contents = [];
$('<div>', {html: message }).find('span.fieldText').each(function(){
  contents.push( $(this).text() );
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/DfDPR/2/

---

Pure javascript

```
var message = currentMarker.get("mensaje");
var contents = [];

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = message;
var spans = div.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var span = 0; span < spans.length; span++)
{
    contents.push(spans[span].innerHTML);
}
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/DfDPR/3/

---

As mentioned in the comments, regex is not a good candidate for parsing HTML...

Answer (score 3):

[Trivial task in jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/JtBxd/):

```
var values = $('span.fieldText', message).map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

`values` will be an array with all the values you need. You can iterate over it or do anything you like.